# Changing WAN to static IP address and Synology NAS

Tags: networking, ip, nas, static-ip

I have a Synology NAS that connects to my AT&T fiber provided modem/router. I have the NAS assigned a static internal IP address like 192.168.1.70. I also have port forwarding rules setup to allow for a webdav/afp connection to my NAS (LAN @ 192.168.1.70) when I am not at home. My modem/routers’ IP address (WAN-facing) is something like 96.76.152.52. As such I can just go to 96.76.152.52:5000 anywhere in the world and access my NAS’s web interface or connect through webdav via 96.76.152.52:5005 with my credentials. This works fine.

However, 96.76.152.52 is a dynamically assigned IP address from my ISP aka it can change (although according to them it rarely will). I wanted to get a static WAN IP address so my router’s IP @ 96.76.152.52 becomes 100.12.122.19 but never changes again. As such, any device connected to my LAN would see 100.12.122.19 when doing findmyip.

So AT&T only leases static IPs as units of 5. Fine. On the phone with the rep, they were telling me that I had to assign my server one of the static IPs, let’s call it 100.12.122.19 and gave me additional details for the subnet mask, gateway, dns server .etc… This is where I got really confused. Why would I configure my server with these IP addresses? Why isn’t my router’s IP of 96.76.152.52 just changing to 100.12.122.19? So I stopped the process so I could better understand what was going on.

To me, I don’t see how changing my server to 100.12.122.19 with a completely different gateway and dns details than my modem/router would work. How would I even connect to my server when I’m local if the IP address isn’t an internal one like 192.168.1.70. I felt like there was a miscommunication, so I explained my setup to them numerous times and the same thing was told to me.

**Can anyone shed light on this? Was the rep simply wrong/confused, or am I missing something?**

https://forums.att.com/conversations/att-internet-features/how-do-i-setup-an-att-internet-static-ip/5defee02bad5f2f606ea4054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When offering you the "5 IP's" - AT&T are not replacing your current IP address with a new one, rather they are routing a subnet of IP address across your existing IP address for your router to handle.  (They are actually giving you 8 IP addresses, but 2 are unusable and 1 is needed by your router leaving 5 for use on your network.

At the bottom of the link in the page you give us it talks about "Static DSL IP to static internet IP".  **This will provide a single IP address that behaves as you want.**  If you can get this without the additional IP's - that is ideally what you want.  Your router IP address will become a static one and everything else can remain as is.   Its wasteful, but if you only get this with a block of static IPs, you could just ignore the block of IP's and it would work as you expect.

A bit more about these Static IP address blocks which might be helpful :

They are useful if you have multiple servers behind your router.
**To use them you may require a better router then the standard home user router many people have**. (You can do this with some knowledge and a SOHO router that runs more advanced software - like dd-wrt)

To use them your router no longer has just a WAN and a LAN - Effectively your router would now heave a WAN and 2 LANS - the existing LAN (in your case with 192.168.70.x on it) and a second LAN with IP addresses your ISP is providing.   When devices on your current LAN - ie 192.168.70.x want to reach devices with a static IP address, traffic will go through the router in one LAN interface and out the other.

I do note that if you have less then 6 devices on your LAN you could simply replace your current 192.168.70.x address with new IP addresses your provider gives you, and reconfigure your router.  This is likely a bad idea though as your devices are more exposed to the Internet and a lot more likely to be hacked.  (Because your current 192.168.70.x is behind NAT the devices can't be reached through the Internet directly unless you do port forwarding)

Comment: It was not what you asked, but there are other ways of achieving your goal without involving AT&T or router changes.   You can set up Dynamic DNS (so your IP address might change but you keep a domain name updated that always points to your current IP address) or you can use a VPN service that offers you a static IP with your NAS (or a decent router!)

Comment: Ok I'm getting there. This still has me tripping up "When devices on your current LAN... router in one LAN interface and out the other." ... So, say I configure the NAS @ 144.157.80.1 from the usable pool of static IPs. On my computer connected to the routers 1st LAN (192.168...) would connect to the NAS via 144.157.80.1 and remotely the same 144.157.80.1, however locally "traffic will go through the router in one LAN interface and out the other [to the NAS]" fe not over the internet? Sounds like some black magic.

Comment: @Alex your understanding of what I wrote is correct.   Its not black Magic though - its the way the whole Internet was designed to work.  (simply/generically speaking) - a router is a device that gets a packet of information, looks at the destination IP address and forwards it out the appropriate interface to the next router or computer.   There is no law that says a router should only have a LAN and a WAN interface - in fact most powerful routers have lots of interfaces....

Comment: A router has a few ways to work out where the traffic gets directed.  If you are familiar with a netmask (eg 255.255.255.0) this is a way of grouping IP's - (in fact the first and last IP's in the range are also involved in this).  Thus router knows what IP addresses it handles directly - ie the LAN connections. The default gateway is the address of another router which traffic the router does not know how to reach can find.  As computers also have a default gateway - ie the router address, they know to send packets outside their subnet to the router.